# using IOUtils.copy on the response outpoutstream inside a Spring controller reset any header modification

Tags: spring-mvc, stream, copy, response, outputstream

I have a simple MVC controller with one endpoint that is meant to return a zip file.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/xxx", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/x-download")
  public String getZip(HttpServletResponse response)
     InputStream is = ...;
     IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
     response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, attachment; filename="myfile.zip");
     return ""; // If I dont return anything (void) headers don't get changed
}
```

When I hit this endpoint with chrome, the response header are missing Content-type and Content-Disposition all together! (normally for all requests I have at least Content-Type=application/json"

I have tried remvoving the IOUtils.copy

And now when I hit the endpoint the header are correct! I do have the right content-type and the content-disposition is there.

Could someone explain me why this is happening? is writing into the outputstream messing up the response?? 
Who do I return a zip in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Set the headers before the copy. I had a similar issue and was able to resolve it this way.

```
InputStream is = ...;
response.setContentType("application/x-download");
response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, attachment;     filename="myfile.zip");
IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
```